# Sql query group by question, creating monthly averages

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I am trying to compile a table which shows three columns:
product name, average monthly sales volume and average monthly sales price for said product.

I am using adventureworks 2019.

I have written the below query based upon some help I previously received.  I have summed the order quantity and unit price for each product and then in the outer query averaged them.

```
SELECT
Product_Name,
AVG(Sales_Volume) AS Avg_Sales_Volume,
AVG(Price) AS Avg_Price


FROM

(SELECT
PP.[Name] AS Product_Name,
SUM(SSOD.[OrderQty]) AS Sales_Volume,
SUM(SSOD.[UnitPrice]) AS Price,
FORMAT(SSOH.[OrderDate], 'MM-yyyy') AS Month_Year

FROM
[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS SSOH
LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SSOD
ON SSOH.SalesOrderID = SSOD.SalesOrderID
LEFT JOIN production.product AS PP
ON SSOD.ProductID = PP.ProductID

GROUP BY PP.[Name], SSOH.[OrderDate]) AS T

--WHERE Product_Name = 'Road-150 Red, 44' (doing this for reference)

GROUP BY T.Product_Name, Month-Year
```

If I group by  Month-Year I get  around 3600  rows, where as if I don't, I get 266. I am confused about this.   Basically, I am not sure what it is actually showing.
To some of you this may seem really basic, but it feels like I cannot get my head around it.

Could anyone take a bit of time to explain this to me?

Thanks

---

```
Product_Name    Avg_Sales_Volume    Avg_Price
LL Mountain Frame - Silver, 48  14  844.96
LL Touring Frame - Blue, 50 26  2100.546
Women's Mountain Shorts, L  13  161.494
Road-550-W Yellow, 44   3   1890.7332
HL Road Frame - Red, 48 18  6025.3137
Mountain-500 Silver, 42 8   1395.0116
```

(266 rows)

Query with group by Month-Year also:

```
Product_Name    Avg_Sales_Volume    Avg_Price
Road-150 Red, 44    1   6758.9544
HL Mountain Frame - Silver, 46  15  4465.6362
AWC Logo Cap    14  76.4672
Long-Sleeve Logo Jersey, L  2   102.611
Road-150 Red, 56    2   6817.546
Mountain-500 Silver, 52 13  2118.7125
LL Touring Frame - Yellow, 62   62  5001.30
ML Mountain Frame-W - Silver, 40    115 6546.3382
```

(3862 rows)

Comment: Seems some typos in that query; are you sure it is accurate/runs?

Comment: And to get this straight, you're saying that when you group by a date that (i guess) goes all the way down to a second precision you get fewer rows than if you group by a date that stops at month? Put both queries, and their output

Comment: `Month-Year` is an arithmetic expression on a column called `Month` and a column called `Year`.  It does not seem particularly useful.

Comment: Hi, the query runs fine.  I will post both outputs here.

Comment: I notice if I group by Month_Year and select a specific product, it will show multiple times, with different sales_Volume and unit prices.  Why is this?  Is it because it cannot show it all as one date (the order date for the product)?

Answer (score 0):

A few notes first, then an explanation of what you're seeing.

First, your outer query has `GROUP BY Month-Year` with a dash, but I believe this is intended to be the column `Month_Year` (with an underscore) from the subquery.

Next, I like your use of `AS` to explicitly define aliases on columns, as well as your use of square brackets `[` and `]` around object names rather than quoted identifiers.

Finally, start getting in the practice of using schema- and alias-identifiers throughout your code - especially when working with subqueries. They'll make it much more clear which objects should be returned, and will prevent "ambiguous column" errors.

Explanation:
The difference in row-counts returned for each of your two queries is due to how those queries instruct the grouping to occur.

`GROUP BY T.Product_Name;` returns 266 rows because it is aggregating all of the sales volume and pricing information for the given product across all time. Changing up your subquery a bit to read:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pp.Name)
  FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS SSOH
  LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SSOD
    ON SSOH.SalesOrderID = SSOD.SalesOrderID
  LEFT JOIN production.product AS PP
    ON SSOD.ProductID = PP.ProductID
```

Results in 266 rows being returned, indicating that there are 266 distinct product names included in that set.

When you add more grouping conditions (such as T.Month_Year), you are telling the engine to make "subgroups" in the aggregation structure.
`GROUP BY T.Product_Name, T.Month_Year` runs your aggregates for each of those distinct 266 product names as well as aggregating the data for each distinct T.Month_Year value that appears in *each* of your 266 product name groups.

Examining those row-counts a bit closer, the two-condition grouping returns 3,862 rows while the single-condition grouping returns 266 rows. Across those 3,862 rows there are 266 distinct product names represented an average of 14.52 times (`3862 / 266 = 15.518...`). If you assumed that every product had at least one sale per month, then you might conclude that we are looking at slightly more than one year's worth of sales data here. More likely, this is a set of several years of sales data with a lot of variation in sales volume and frequency between products.

ADDENDUM: Adding your `GROUP BY` columns to the `SELECT` illustrates the difference in result sets:

```
SELECT Product_Name,
       T.Month_Year,
       AVG(Sales_Volume) AS Avg_Sales_Volume,
       AVG(Price) AS Avg_Price
  FROM (SELECT PP.[Name] AS Product_Name,
               SUM(SSOD.[OrderQty]) AS Sales_Volume,
               SUM(SSOD.[UnitPrice]) AS Price,
               FORMAT(SSOH.[OrderDate], 'MM-yyyy') AS Month_Year
          FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS SSOH
          LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SSOD
            ON SSOH.SalesOrderID = SSOD.SalesOrderID
          LEFT JOIN production.product AS PP
            ON SSOD.ProductID = PP.ProductID
         GROUP BY PP.[Name], SSOH.[OrderDate]) AS T
--WHERE Product_Name = 'Road-150 Red, 44' (doing this for reference)
 GROUP BY T.Product_Name,
          T.Month_Year
 ORDER BY Product_Name;
```

Examining the results shows that each product name also has records for any month in which that product sold:

```
+--------------------------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|        ProductName       | Month_Year|Avg_Vol| Avg_Price |
+--------------------------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|  All-Purpose Bike Stand  |  12-2013  |   1   | 193.0714  |
|  All-Purpose Bike Stand  |  06-2014  |   1   | 218.625   |
|  All-Purpose Bike Stand  |  05-2014  |   1   | 187.909   |
|  All-Purpose Bike Stand  |  10-2013  |   1   | 212.00    |
|  AWC Logo Cap            |  02-2014  |   6   | 57.7928   |
|  AWC Logo Cap            |  02-2012  |   48  | 93.357    |
|  AWC Logo Cap            |  08-2011  |   68  | 103.73    |
|  AWC Logo Cap            |  01-2013  |   124 | 129.4896  |
|  AWC Logo Cap            |  03-2014  |   21  | 71.1747   |
+--------------------------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation.  Actually, the sales date spans from 2011 - 2014 iirc.  I understood where you are coming from though.  Is this showing the average Monthly sales volumes and prices though?  I am still unsure how I should be getting there.

Comment: If I use Month(OrderDate), then average this, would it work?  I see I can possibly do this, but I remember the answer is something similar to above.  I am not sure if I should be using this query to then write a dax expression in powerbi to create monthly values.

Comment: I updated my answer to better show what's happening with your grouping